# Symfony, minMessage from Constraints not displaying

Tags: symfony, constraints, symfony-3.4

I'm new to Symfony and just making my first Project with the 3.4 version.
I have a problem when using Constraints on my form, I'm trying to make a field having some Length constraints, but as I test it with a short value that shouldn't be accepted, the form displays a default message in a speech bubble instead of the one I put in minMessage, and instead of displaying a message for maxLength, it just don't let me put more thant 20 characters in the field instead of displaying a message if there is more than 20. I'm not sure this is how it should work (???) and if it is can I manage error messages with another technic? I'm just putting constraints on a single field until I resolved this issue that's why the others one don't have any.
Here's the Controller Code :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Form\UserType;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * Class UserController
 * @package AppBundle\Controller
 * @Route("/user")
 */

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     * @Route("/add", name="add_user")
     */
    public function addAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
            $user->setPwd(md5($user->getPwd()));
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->render('@App/User/show.html.twig', array(
                'user'=>$user
            ));
        }
        return $this->render('@App/User/add.html.twig', array(
            'form'=>$form->createView()
        ));
    }

}
```

UserType code:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('pseudo')
                ->add('nom')
                ->add('prenom')
                ->add('enseignant')
                ->add('pwd', PasswordType::class)
                ->add('confirm_pwd', PasswordType::class);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_user';
    }


}
```

User code (I'll just pute the code where my constraints are):

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="pseudo", type="string", length=100, unique=true)
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min = 8,
     *      max = 20,
     *      minMessage = "Your first name must be at least {{ limit }} characters long",
     *      maxMessage = "Your first name cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters"
     * )
     */
    private $pseudo;
}
```

And the twig page that I render:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1 class="display-4">Formulaire d'inscription</h1>
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.pseudo, {'label': 'Pseudo', 'attr':
    {'placeholder': 'Pseudonyme ...'}}) }}
    {{ form_row(form.nom, {'label': 'Nom', 'attr':
    {'placeholder': 'Nom ...'}}) }}
    {{ form_row(form.prenom, {'label': 'Prenom', 'attr':
    {'placeholder': 'Prenom ...'}}) }}
    {{ form_row(form.enseignant, {'label': 'Enseignant'}) }}
    {{ form_row(form.pwd, {'label': 'Mot De Passe', 'attr':
    {'placeholder': 'Mot De Passe'}}) }}
    {{ form_row(form.confirm_pwd, {'label': 'Confirmation Mot De Passe', 'attr':
    {'placeholder': 'Mot De Passe'}}) }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Inscription </button>
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Do you know what should I do to make it work?
I am sorry if my english is bad, and tell me if you need more or less code!
Have a nice day and thank you !

PS: I'm a real beginner with Symfony so be nice pls :)
PSbis: I already checked the documentation and I made everything that should have been made, but I could have missed something (even if I checked multiple times)

Edit: I added EqualTo and Unique constraints on other fields, and both error messages are displaying, so this is comming from the Length constraint and I really don't know why

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting to add `form_errors`. Check [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#form-errors-form-view) out.

Comment: I tried doing this, it displays the errors twice, all the constraints I added have their error messages working except for the Length one, it doesn't displays the message, it opens a speech bubble that has nothing to do with the one I code in my css having a default message, it is like these Length error are not treated the same way as the others. I can't write more thant the max Length and the default message is only displaying when the "pseudo" is too short. I don't know if I explained it clearly let me know

Comment: It should behave the same (looking at your code, I can’t find any reason why is not working the same)